# How to make a pandas series with various numbers ordered?

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a series in pandas that has different numbers and different quantities of each number. They are not scattered in the series, they come as cycles and when one ends, another one starts.

Here's what it looks like as a list:

```
[nan, nan, nan, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 6.0, 6.0, 6.0, 6.0, 6.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, …]
```

I want the numbers to be ordered in an increasing order without skipping any number (e.g 1,2,3,4,5,6, etc.)

so all 4's will become 3's, 6's will become 4's, 11's will become 5's and so on...

Comment: check `Series.rank(method='dense')` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rank.html?highlight=rank#pandas.Series.rank

Comment: `a =[nan, ...., 1.0, 1.0, ...]` and then `pd.Series.rank( pd.Series(a),method = 'dense')`